# Solution for page that has unknown number of form. How to handle?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, jsp, form-submit

I've got  a problem with my website.
I want to create a page that has many form (something like comment form for unknown number of post). One more thing i want is to submit comment form without refreshing my page.
With known number of form, i can solve my problem with ajax. But with unknown number, i do not know how to name those forms, how to write jquery code to solve!!
PS: my webpage is written in JSP.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Would it be viable to do something like Facebook where you need to click on "add comment" before the form appears, that way you could insert the form using Javascript and you'd be guaranteed to only have one form on the page at a time.

Comment: Thanks, great idea.
But in facebook, it always display many form, isn't it?
Beside, as you said, each form belongs to one specific post, so it has it own id or name. How to write javascript to handle all these form??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to name all the form, you can use jquery **[closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)** function to get the value of your form. some thing like this

​

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="comment">
<input type="hidden" name="usrid" value="1">
<input type="button" class="submitbut" value="Submit">
</form><br/>

<form>
<input type="text" name="comment">
<input type="hidden" name="usrid" value="2">
    <input type="button" class="submitbut" value="Submit">
</form><br/>

<form>
<input type="text" name="comment">
<input type="hidden" name="usrid" value="3">
    <input type="button" class="submitbut" value="Submit">
</form>
```

​
  And the Jquery

```
$(".submitbut").click(function() {
    alert($(this).closest("form").serialize());
});​
```

and here is the jsfiddle to help you out. **[click here](http://jsfiddle.net/BYZg2/)**

*Updated Since OP needs to use Jquery validate*

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BYZg2/2/)

Comment: Thanks, hope this method works well with "validate" function :D

Comment: @Songokute i have updated my answer to use jquery validate too..pls check

Comment: @Songokute mark this answer as selected if you got your answers..thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have written a small script that is designed to handle such a situation where you need one controller to handle multiple scripts.

The script has a switch statement that lets you handle certain scripts to have a specific call back. All other scripts will run the callback in the "default" case of the switch statement. Those callbacks are for you to put any code that needs to run on success of the ajax submission of the form.

Here is the link 
https://github.com/andresgallo/FORM-POSTER-using-AJAX-and-JQUERY/blob/master/ajaxFormPoster.js

Hope it helps